# How to stick data on widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, sharedpreferences

I am using FutureBuilder to load my data from shared preferences... here is my code

```
Future getData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String dataIn = prefs.getString("clockin");
    return dataIn;
  }

Widget defaultClock() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        if (snap.hasData) {
          return Text(snap.data);
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

using that code... data will always check first... is data exist or not...if not it will return CircularProgressIndicator() first and when ConnectionState.done and snap.hasData==true it will return the data... so... instead of using Future Builder, is there another method so that the data will always stick in my widget without any process like CircularProgressIndicator() when I open my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible. It is because you are using a **Future** builder. The data will arrive some time in the future - be it 30 miliseconds or 3 seconds.

Alternative is - you fetch the data in the previous screen and call this screen along with the data. Example :

screen1.dart calls screen2 as :

```
 string _data = await getData();
 _loadNextScreen(_data);



void _loadNextScreen(string data) {

    Navigator.push(
       context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) =>
            MyNextScreen(data: _data)
     ),
  );

}
```

Now, in screen2, you don't need to have CircularProcessIndicator() or like.

Comment: is there another method instead of Future Builder to stick my data in parent when calling shared preferences?

Comment: Certainly. However, in theory, it works the same way as Futurebuilder. If you don't want to use 'Futurebuilder' then you'll have to write the code which works in the same way. It is using setState(). I can provide a sample if that would help you. Having said that, 'FutureBuilder' is A. readymade  B. efficient; and more importatly, it is alwasy good to stick with what is readymade than writing our own code :)

Comment: would you like to give me a sample code of that by editing my code?

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/2xqvar5z) is an example. _requestCriminalsFromAPI() makes an API call (in your case, it's a shared prefs). Before the data is loaded, _isLoadingCompleted is false and it is set to true after the data is loaded. the widget's body part is made to show either a progressbar or the actual widget based on true/false. (Note : The code is under construction and may not be in the best shape) :)

Comment: Did it help ? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi.. sorry for my late reply... yesterday I have not had time to try .. but I'm trying it now.. I will let you know the result

Comment: I have tried your code.. and the way how app runs is like FutureBuilder...it will wait until the data is completely loaded.. so like what you said before... the only one method to stick data inside my widget is...fetch the data in the previous screen and call this screen along with the data, right ?